# Facebook SDK - iOS6 login popup cannot be dismissed

Tags: facebook, ios5, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

In my iPhone app, I want the user to be able to share a link on Facebook.

When they click "share", I use the following code to login to Facebook using the new SDK 3.1, then use `FBRequestConnection` in the completion handler (a simple `publish_action`).

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:true completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

    // Now call FBRequestConnection to post in the stream

}];
```

When the user has the Facebook app installed, it just delegates the login to the app. However when they don't, it opens the login page in a WebView.

In iOS 5, it opens Mobile Safari:

[image]

My problem is on iOS 6, I get the same flow but in a modal popup instead (on top of my app).

[image]

I have 2 issues with the popup:

**1. Closing it**

It cannot be cancelled or dismissed. In comparison, the **HelloFacebookSample** app from the SDK has the same popup but with a cross button to close it.

[image]

*NOTE:* now solved thanks to *ravi*, I was missing the Facebook resource bundle which contains the "close" image.

**2. Accepting the permissions**

On the second step of the popup (see screens above), pressing *Okay* doesn't do anything. Pressing the "X" calls the completion handler with an error, which is great, but nothing happens with *Okay*. Is this the right way to login to Facebook with the SDK 3.1? Am I missing a callback to react to the popup specifically?

Some more clarifications:

> This only happens in **iOS6** when the Facebook app is **not
>   installed** and the Facebook account is **not configured** in the iOS
>   settings.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 im having similar problem after FB is updated to 3.0SDk

Comment: Might be a bug in the SDK. Just a note; Facebook encourages asking for publish permissions when you're actually publishing (and not when connecting): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

Comment: Thanks Kristofer - by "execute a publish_action later on" I actually meant as soon as the login callback arrives. I think that should be OK

Comment: The reason that read and publish permission requests have been split has been to ensure that the user feels comfortable with an application before it starts posting on their behalf. Requesting publish permissions back-to-back after logging in is going to give you just as much of a drop off in permission acceptance. (Plus more actions you're expecting the user to take to get started)

Comment: For the moment the app doesn't do anything until the user chooses to post on Facebook, after which it logs in using **openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions**, then posts using **FBRequestConnection**. Is that acceptable? From what I understand, you say I'll have to be careful when the app starts logging in to Facebook at startup?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to ask for publish permissions first (and only)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. In summary, I'm happy with the way we ask for permissions now (taken from the Facebook samples), but don't understand why we get stuck on the popup.

Comment: [Here][1] is what I've done to solve this problem. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712824/facebook-login-dialog-does-not-work-on-ios6-simulator/13031521#13031521

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I can't comment as my reputation is less than 50, so trying to point out my observations as answer.*

I too noticed this problem when using **Facebook sdk3.1 on ios6**. In my case I'm using the old style facebook object creation and call `[facebook authorize:permissions]` on it, but I modified the source code to always use "`FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView`" so that my login is always through in-app web login.

In my case I was missing FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle and FacebookSDKResources.bundle, so I was unable to see the cross button (but I was able to tap on that spot and getting call back `- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled` {) .

Comment: Thanks so much, this is definitely a step in the right direction! I was missing the resource bundle too. I can now see and tap the close button. The "Okay" button on the right still doesn't do anything though, which could be a different issue.

Comment: even after adding FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle and FacwebookSDKResources.bundle  i can't see cancel button..

Comment: @ravi: if you don't mind me asking, what do you get that second popup WebView saying `You have already authorized this app [Okay]`? And if so, do you know which method gets called when you click `Okay`? I can't seem to understand why mine isn't wired properly.

Comment: @Gromix: I tried removing the FB app , removed IOS FB credentials. I ran the Hackbook sample on my ios6 Device , but i didn't see the second popup Webview which u mentioned. **But few weeks back i read on SO itself by Facebook engineer saying that the okay button is not working , in the sense its not opening the app again. They planned to fix it in the next dot release** _I tried to look for the link where i read this but couldn't find_

Comment: @Gromix: try to ask user [http://stackoverflow.com/users/1025173/shireesh-asthana ] regarding the OAuth workflow and switching to app when okay is clicked

Comment: That would explain it, although Hackbook also seems to work for me. I have custom URL handlers so it could be a strange combination blocking the iOS6 OAuth (but not iOS5?). I'll keep an eye on Shireesh's posts and on the new release! In the meantime I changed it so iOS6 users can only post using native integration, but not login. Hopefully I figure out a working OAuth flow soon - thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: wheres the sample HelloFacebookSample project found?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/ have instructions to install and once u download the sdk , you can find samples

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue and it does appear to be a known bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/539702426044893?browse=search_507daefc9af416244781488

I haven't resolved the issue yet, but for me it only seem to happen in the simulator.  My app seems to always login through safari when installed on a device

Edit:  So after a little more digging I came across this stack overflow thread: 
[FBConnect login, share with a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819876/fbconnect-login-share-with-a-webview)

I realized that the dialog we're seeing is a uiWebView which is actually the fallback if the app is unable to open the dialog in safari.  I was able to work around my issue my reseting my simulator, which would essentially clean out the cookies.  From your screen shot I believe you are working in the simulator too.  I wonder if you reset the simulator if you would have the same results?

From the menu iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...